# Регулярное выражение для href='

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ссылки, php

Необходимо сделать замену значения href у ссылок (заменить `href='такая_то_страница.html'` на `href='/такая_то_страница.html'`)

делаю так

```
$txt = preg_replace("/href='[^/]/","href='/", $txt);
```

но выходит пустая белая страница. Если

```
$txt = preg_replace("/href='[^\/]/","href='/", $txt);
```

то ссылки заменяются, но результат получается таким
href='/ndex.php'
т.е срезается первая буква!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$txt = preg_replace("/href='([^']+)/","href='/$1", $txt);
```

Т.е заменяем после кавычки все, что не кавычка( **`[^']`** ), в кол-ве более одного (**+**), на слэш + первое вхождение (**`$1`**)

чтобы только без слэша в начале:

```
$txt2 = preg_replace("/href='([^'\/]+)/","href='/$1", $txt);
```

Comment: Нет. Ссылки вообще не заменяются. ( Есть еще мысли?

Comment: http://sh4dow.ru/test.php это не может не работать)

Comment: Да, извините моя невнимательность! Вместо ' (апострофа) поставил "(кавычку) и еще нюанс, подскажите, если вам не трудно: если ссылка будет уже со слэшем, `href='/такая_то_страница.html'`, то она попадает под условия поиска и преобразует в `href='//такая_то_страница.html'`

Как можно переделать это условие, чтоб ссылки со слэшем не редактировались?

Comment: Обновил ответ. Тест пока там же.

Comment: Ооо! спасибо вам огромное,выручили!

Comment: Не за что) Нажмите галку слева от вопроса, чтоб не висел в "непринятым"